# Login Loop - TFS Plugin - Eclipse Oxygen

Tags: eclipse, tfs, eclipse-plugin, azure-devops

Getting the following error when trying to connect to a VSTS server through the Eclipse TFS plugin.

I get the OAuth2 window that asks for my credentials. 
When i type in my email hernando.hoyos@axa-equitable.com i get redirected and an IE window quickly opens then closes. 
This is what the log says but i dont really understand the error. 
Anyone any ideas?

Thanks in advance,

> 2017-03-08 12:00:10,957 INFO  [main]
>   (com.microsoft.tfs.core.config.httpclient.DefaultHTTPClientFactory)
>   HttpClient configured for https://app.vssps.visualstudio.com,
>   authenticating with JWT token 2017-03-08 12:00:11,526 WARN  [main]
>   (com.microsoft.tfs.core.httpclient.HttpMethodBase) Cookie rejected:
>   "$Version=0;
>   VstsSession={"PersistentSessionId":"4f82d81f-9717-4f3f-8e20-90ea99355026","PendingAuthenticationSessionId":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000","CurrentAuthenticationSessionId":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"};
>   $Path=/; $Domain=.visualstudio.com". Domain attribute
>   ".visualstudio.com" violates RFC 2109: host minus domain may not
>   contain any dots 2017-03-08 12:00:11,527 INFO  [main]
>   (com.microsoft.alm.auth.pat.VstsPatAuthenticator) Retrieving
>   PersonalAccessToken for uri:https://axa-us.visualstudio.com with
>   name:TEE: https://axa-us.visualstudio.com on: USLINY2PC09F8KW, and
>   with scope:, prompt behavior: AUTO 2017-03-08 12:00:13,316 WARN 
>   [main] (com.microsoft.tfs.client.common.credentials.CredentialsHelper)
>   Failed to authenticate interactively with web browser. This requires
>   either JavaFX or SWT based web browser control: 2017-03-08
>   12:00:13,316 WARN  [main]
>   (com.microsoft.tfs.client.common.credentials.CredentialsHelper) 1.
>   JavaFX web browser control is only supported on Oracle Java SE 7
>   update 6 or higher, Oracle Java SE 8, or OpenJDK 8 runtime (Please
>   note you may need to compile OpenJFX project yourself). 2017-03-08
>   12:00:13,316 WARN  [main]
>   (com.microsoft.tfs.client.common.credentials.CredentialsHelper) 2. To
>   launch SWT browser with a specific XULRunner, please set the value of
>   Java system property 'org.eclipse.swt.browser.XULRunnerPath' to the
>   full path of the specific XULRunner. 2017-03-08 12:00:13,316 INFO 
>   [CancellableCommandThread-92]
>   (com.microsoft.tfs.client.common.ui.config.UITransportRequestHandler) 
>   Credentials dialog has been cancelled by the user. 2017-03-08
>   12:00:13,316 WARN  [CancellableCommandThread-92]
>   (com.microsoft.tfs.core.TFSConfigurationServer) Error getting data
>   provider
>   com.microsoft.tfs.core.ws.runtime.exceptions.TransportRequestHandlerCanceledException:
>   User canceled transport request handling  at
>   com.microsoft.tfs.core.ws.runtime.client.SOAPService.executeSOAPRequest(SOAPService.java:475)
>     at
>   ms.ws._LocationWebServiceSoap12Service.connect(_LocationWebServiceSoap12Service.java:385)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.tfs.core.clients.framework.location.internal.LocationWebServiceProxy.connect(LocationWebServiceProxy.java:58)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.tfs.core.clients.framework.location.LocationService.connect(LocationService.java:719)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.tfs.core.TFSConfigurationServer.getServerDataProvider(TFSConfigurationServer.java:254)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.tfs.core.TFSConnection.authenticate(TFSConnection.java:788)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.tfs.client.common.ui.commands.ConnectToConfigurationServerCommand.doRun(ConnectToConfigurationServerCommand.java:164)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.tfs.client.common.framework.command.Command.run(Command.java:92)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.tfs.client.common.framework.command.RunnableCommandAdapter.run(RunnableCommandAdapter.java:95)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Comment: Eclipse Oxygen is still under development and won't be fully released until June 2017. Are you sure TFS has been tested with this release? Eclipse Neon.2 (4.6.2) is the current stable release.

Comment: I am not sure, I have neon installed I will test and let you know Thanks again

Comment: That fixed the problem. I tested in a Eclipse Mars Installation that i had and i was able to connect without any problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is Using Eclipse Mars or Eclipse Neon.

Answer (score 0):

I installed eclipse Oxygen today and I installed the TFS plugin this site: http://dl.microsoft.com/eclipse/tfs and it is working well.

Window > Install new software > http://dl.microsoft.com/eclipse/tfs

Comment: Answers are better received when they provide an explanation to their working